# Need to add virtual interface in Suse Enterprise Server edition permanently

Tags: networking, suse

How can I add virtual interface in SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 permanently?

Answer (score 2):

If using a static configuration and without NetworkManager enabled you have to set an IP address and a netmask
or prefix length with **IPADDR**, **NETMASK** or **PREFIXLEN** variables in /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-INTERFACE_IDENTIFIER file.

For multiple addresses use these variables multiple times and extend them with
different suffixes. For example **IPADDR_1=**, **IPADDR_2=**, **NETMASK_1=**, **NETMASK_2=** and so on. See section 'Multiple
addresses' in  **ifcfg** manpage).

Answer (score 2):

By using the `vconfig` command:

```
# vconfig add eth0 5
```

This option is good if you use DHCP, if the vlan already on the switch port and is generating DHCP she will automatically get the address:

```
# ifconfig eth0.5
```

If vlan will have a static address then use:

```
# ifconfig eth0.5 192.168.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255 up
```